# How Do Use Ajax to Load Content into Targeted Div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I would like to load all my links to my pages with content into a `div` I tried. I think I am having difficulty doing this because of the `id` or the `class` of the links to load into the targeted `div`.

The `div` I want to load the content into is `div#Pages` and The links - `a` tags - in my navigation have `three-d` class name, how do I get the links to load into the `div#Pages`

I am using Bootstrap framework.

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="myContent" style="background-color: white; padding: 5px 10px; opacity:.5; height:100% !important; border-left-color:black; border-left-width:15px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    The content in this div will hide and<br> show (toggle) when the toggle is pressed. 
    <br><Br><br><br><br><br>
    <hr>Put Advertisement in this space here<br><br><br><br>Put Copyright Claims here<br>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container-fluid">
    <div id="pages">
        <center>PUT ALL FONT ON HERE THERE YEAH</center>
    </div>
</div>  

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
            <center><a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');"> <img src="images/equalize_lq.gif" width="100" height="49"> <br><font size=".5em">Show Player</font></a></center>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
            <ul class="block-menu" id="navmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="/" class="three-d">Home
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
                        <span class="front">Home</span>
                        <span class="back">Home</span>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/demos" class="three-d">Artist
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
                        <span class="front">Roster</span>
                        <span class="back">Roster</span>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="pages/order.html" class="three-d">Labels
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
                        <span class="front">Labels</span>
                        <span class="back">Labels</span>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/" class="three-d">Music
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
                        <span class="front">Music</span>
                        <span class="back">Music</span>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/" class="three-d">Videos
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
                            <span class="front">Videos</span>
                            <span class="back">Videos</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/" class="three-d">Store
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
                            <span class="front">Store</span>
                            <span class="back">Store</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/" class="three-d">Services
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
                            <span class="front">Services</span>
                            <span class="back">Services</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"> SOCIAL MEDIA LINKS HERE</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is Some code I got off of **youtube** to try to use but doesn't seem to work for me or I could be doing this wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //trigger and container//
    var trigger = $('#navmenu ul li a'),
    container = $('#pages');

    //Fire on click//
    trigger.on('click', function () {

    //set for reuse//

    var $this = $(this);
    target = $this.data('target');

    //Load Target Page into Container//
    container.load(target + '.html');

    //Stop Normal Link behavior//
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Some code that you have tried that we might assist you with will allow us to help you out here.

Comment: Sure Im editing the post now

Answer (score 0):

You can send and receive AJAX call as follows

```
 $.get("http://URL/ACTIONNAME?PARA1="+para1+"&"+"PARA2="+para2,function(data){
                        $("#Pages").html(data);
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'd be using jQuery for it.

```
//handle 'click' on any <a class="three-d" /> element
$("body").on("click", "a.three-d", function (e) {
    //get URL from link
    var url = $(this).prop("href");

    //load http content into main div.
    $("#pages").load(url);

    //prevent link to be redirected
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: I thought this would work but its not and I need it to load by ID not class the classes on the links are assigned to css to animate my navigation on hover.... and yes I will most likely be using jQuery @thiagopxp

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button name/id').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : '//controller name',
            data : { // all the data to be passed to fetch )},
            success : function(responseText) {
                var p="=Succesfull";
                if(p==responseText) {
                $('#name or id of div').text(responseText);
                 $('#submit2').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text(responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Try to writelike above
 by using either Id or name of div

Comment: NO this still jumps to the page instead of loading into the div

Comment: Do u want 2 html pages in one page

Comment: if that is the case than try <iframe src="/yourpage.jsp"></iframe> within div instead of a href

Comment: NO I do not want 2 html pages inside of one page..... i just want the navigation to load one page upon click into the div? this is becoming very frustrating

Comment: why dont u used response redirect instead of href in ajax on click of link,                  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pathname,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.redirect) {
        window.location = data.redirectURL;
      }
    },